# Let me know the script to get a file with the same name in another path

Tags: windows-8

An image with the .avi extension exists in the A folder. (A / eat / action1.avi), (A/talk/d_action3.avi) ...

Could you copy the files in the destination path by navigating to the above file name (action1, d_action3 ...)? (The file name is the same, only the extension is different.)

The destnatio folder is B/P01/action1.bin, B/P01/action1.txt ....
B/P10/d_action3.bin
B/P10/d_action3.txt...

thank you.

It's a logic I thought of.

```py
dest = 'C:/B'
for folder_list in myfolder('C:/A')
    for avifile in folder_list
        mylist = search(avifile.name, dest) 
        cp(mylist, folder_list)
```

Comment: Can you plz elaborate your requirements by giving more specific paths and file names ?

Comment: @NirajGajjar 1. C:\Users\user-1\Desktop\source, there is a movie file in the child folder. 2. C:\Users\user-1\Desktop\dest, there are txt and bin files with the same name in the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) cmdlet to retrieve all files within a folder. To retrieve the filename without extension, you can simply use the returned `BaseName` property.

This is how you get a list of all source files from the source folder that have a file with the same name in the destination folder and copy to a folder called "target":

```
$destinationFiles = Get-ChildItem .\destination\ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
Get-ChildItem .\source\ | Where-Object BaseName -in $destinationFiles |  Copy-Item -Destination .\target\
```